# Etale topos as a classifyng topos ?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, topos-theory

Hello !

If $X$ is a scheme, we can consider the etale topos of $X$ whose object are etale scheme above $X$ with the etale topology.

My question is : is there a know way to express this topos as the classifying topos of some geometric theory ? Of course it is possible, just because it's a grothendieck topos, but I'm looking for an explicit theory at least on some particular case (like when $X$ is affine, or when $X$ is the spectrum of the ring of integer of a number field, or when $X$ is a projective curve over a finite field... )

For example, if $A$ is a ring, then the Zariski topos of $Spec A$ (topos of finite presentation scheme above $Spec A$ with the Zariski topology) is the classifying topos of the theory of local $A$ algebra. (the universal local $A$ algebra being the structural sheaf).

Comment: I think this answers your question (at least for the affine case): http://mathoverflow.net/questions/48690/what-does-an-etale-topos-classify

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I cannot give the details, but my guess is that the etale topos should be the classifying topos of the theory of strictly local $A$ algebras. By a *strictly local* $A$ algebra I mean a henselian local algebra with separably closed residue field. I don't know if this is a honest algebraic theory.

Bonus: in this vein the Nisnevich topos should be the classifying topos of the theory of henselian local $A$ algebras. The proof should follow similar lines to the previous one.

Comment: The link by Achilleas K supports your guess.