# Classifying toposes of theories of rings that aren't local rings

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, topos-theory

The standard uses of toposes in algebraic geometry come from sites that look roughly like the syntactic sites of theories of local rings that they classify. This isn't particularly surprising, since this corresponds to allowing localizations as coverings in the site. Are there any interesting uses of classifying toposes of theories of rings that are not necessarily local?

Comment: Are you asking for example of interesting Grothendieck topology on the category of affine scheme which do not contains the Zariski topology ?

Comment: @SimonHenry That, plus some description of the resulting topos as the classifying topos of a theory of rings.

Comment: Well the theory of all rings is classified by the category of functors from finitely-presented rings to Sets. I do not know any other example of such topos used in algebraic geometry, but maybe a geometer can comment on this.

Comment: There are examples where the rings are not *just* local, but this is probably not what you want.

Comment: @DavidRoberts That's okay. What kinds of examples are you thinking of? This is more of a question of curiosity than necessity.

Comment: Check out the work of Ingo Blechschmidt, eg section 21 of https://rawgit.com/iblech/internal-methods/master/notes.pdf, where he looks at what the étale topos classifies, and what the 'surjective' topos classifies. There are others that he's looked at, but I can't find them right now. See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/330344/classifying-space-of-valuation-ringed-spaces-over-a-topos/330363#330363

Comment: Aha, here it is: https://tcsc.lakecomoschool.org/files/2018/07/Blechschmidt.pdf see the last two slides, and see also work of Hutzler (eg https://dmv2019.math.kit.edu/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/Hutzler_IniToposClassTopos.pdf)

Comment: Sorry for storm of replies, but here is Hutzler's thesis, _[Internal language and classified theories of
toposes in algebraic geometry](https://gitlab.com/MatthiasHu/master-thesis/raw/master/thesis.pdf)_

Comment: Hutzler’s description of the infinitesimal topology fits the bill. Please post it as an answer so I can accept it.